# css transform scale and jquery bug

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I am using css to scale an element on this page, and for some strange reason it's moving and stretching the images within the element in Chrome. Works perfectly fine in Safari.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />  
        <title>title</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js'></script>  
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="posts_container">
        <div class="post">
        <div class="post_content">
            <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5e4ioVQsj1qbzzgco1_1280.gif" alt="" />
            <div class="post_tools">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Source: noirlac</a>
                <a href="#" class="tag">#gif</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_info">
            <div class="portrait"></div>
                <div class="from">
                    <a href="#">robotoperator</a>
                    <div class="reblogged"></div>
                    <a href="#">ary</a>
                </div>
                <div class="scale">
                    <a href="#" class="likes"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="reblog"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="note_count">1,747</a>    
                </div>
        </div>
        <img class="point" src="point.png" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="post">
        <div class="post_content">
            <h2>Where's my sandwich?</h2>
            <p>Seriously, where is it?</p>
            <div class="post_tools">
                <a href="#" class="tag">#where are you sandwich?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="point" src="point.png" alt="" />
        <div class="post_info">
            <div class="portrait"></div>
                <div class="from">
                    <a href="#">robotoperator</a>   
                </div>
                <div class="scale">
                    <a href="#" class="likes"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="reblog"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="note_count">5</a>    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="post">
        <div class="post_content">
            <iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:2dam1YcpllKLaeIunQvIrV" width="640" height="720" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
            <div class="post_tools">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Source: Spotify</a>
                <a href="#" class="tag">#music</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_info">
            <div class="portrait"></div>
                <div class="from">
                    <a href="#">robotoperator</a>
                    <div class="reblogged"></div>
                    <a href="#">anamanaguchi</a>
                </div>
                <div class="scale">
                    <a href="#" class="likes"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="reblog"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="note_count">12</a>   
                </div>  
        </div>
        <img class="point" src="point.png" alt="" />
        </div>  

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #2c4762;
}

#posts_container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 664px;
    margin: 120px 0px 0px -332px;
    padding: 0px 0px 120px 0px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post {
    width: 662px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    font-family: helvetica neue, sans-serif;
}

    .post_content {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.46);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.46);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.46);
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
    }

        .post_content iframe {
            margin: 6px 0px -10px -4px;
        }

        .post_content img {
            margin: 1px 0px -10px -4px;
            padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
            width: 639px;
        }

        .post_content h2 {
            color: #444;
            margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
        }

        .post_content p {
            margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 19px;
        }

            .post_content p a {
                color: #111;
            }

        .post_content blockquote {
            font-size: 14px;
            border-left: #ddd 3px solid;
            margin: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
        }

.post_tools {
    border-top: #d7d7d7 1px solid;
    margin: 20px 0px -15px -15px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 662px;
    background: #eee;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

    .post_tools .tag {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #898989;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .post_tools .tag:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

.post_info {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: -64px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 30px;
}

    .post_info a {
        color: #b2bbc4;
        text-decoration: none;
    }   

    .note_count, .reblog, .likes {
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline;
        float: right;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    }   


    .post_info .note_count {
        padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #405971;
    }

    .post_info .reblog {
        display: block;
        width: 31px;
        height: 26px;
        background: #405971 url('tool_sprite.png') no-repeat -53px 2px;
    }

    .post_info .likes {
        display: block;
        width: 28px;
        height: 26px;
        background: #405971 url('tool_sprite.png') no-repeat -86px 4px;
    }

    .post_info .portrait {
        background: url('avatar.png');
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

.point { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 104px;
    left: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.from {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    left: 110px;
    height: 21px;
    width: 300px;
}

.reblogged {
    width: 25px;
    height: 21px;
    background: url('tool_sprite.png') no-repeat -56px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.from a, .reblogged {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.scale {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 26px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8,0.8);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.post').hoverIntent( function() {
        $('.post_info', this).delay(500).animate({ 'opacity': '1', 'margin-top': '-10px' }, 300);
        $(this).delay(500).animate({ 'margin-bottom': '-10px' }, 300);
        $('.point', this).delay(720).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 100);
    }, function () {
        $('.post_info', this).delay(500).animate({'opacity': '0', 'margin-top': '-50px' }, 300);
        $(this).delay(500).animate({ 'margin-bottom': '-64px' }, 300);
        $('.point', this).delay(500).animate({'opacity': '0'}, 100);
    });     
});
```

The things that are being scaled are the three post controls to the right at the bottom of each post on hover.

How can I fix this issue?

(Please note the edit with the added jsfiddle does not demonstrate the bug — you need to view the linked page to see it in action)

Comment: If you animate to `opacity: .999` instead of `opacity:1` it looks much better, but there are still 2px at the top that don't look quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `.scale` css rule to following.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="likes">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.scale {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 26px;
 }
 .post_info .likes {
     display: block;
     /* remove all other rules from here and assign to span */
 }
 .scale a span {
     display: block;
     width: 28px;
     height: 26px;
     background: #405971 url('http://ra.gs/tumblr/tool_sprite.png') no-repeat -86px 4px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 }
```

Comment: The problem still occurs for me. Chrome on Windows 8.

Comment: Okay I made the changes — it turns out the problem is associated with the applied border-radius? If you un-comment out the last bit of css on the updated page, the problem returns